# JOptionPane how to call custom buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

Hey I made a custom JOptionPane that shows multiple custom buttons

```
String [] codeVlakken = {"Kleur 1", "Kleur 2", "Kleur 3", "Kleur 4" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, code , "Cheat menu", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, codeVlakken, "" );
```

So in the first line I defined what is in my array and on the second line at the end I placed my array name so it will fill it up with my custom named buttons.

Now I want to give each custom button a different color, how can I call "Kleur 1" for example from it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `options` parameter takes a type of `Object[]`

Instead of using an array of `String`s, try using an array of `JButton`s.

This would allow you to create and define the properties of buttons before you add then to the dialog

**Updated**

```
JButton [] codeVlakken = {JButton("Kleur 1")};
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, code , "Cheat menu", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, codeVlakken, "" );
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? I don't think I quite understand it.

Comment: @Glenndisimo Replace your array of Strings, with an array of JButtons ... Couldn't be simpler